# Play Sound with Honeywell Captuvo SL22 device

Tags: ios, audio, honeywell

I would like to play a sound from the skid before and/or after a successful scan with different tones.

It has a higher pitched speaker or piezo electric device that's easier to hear in our current environment as opposed to using the ipod speaker.

Also, I'm familiar with Linea Pro devices and they can play sounds by calling via their DTDevice playSound method.

Has anyone been able to play sounds on demand via the Honeywell Captuvo devices yet?

Scenario 1:
The scanner beeps when I scan anything, then if the item is NOT in inventory, I'd like to play a different tone, from the API, and play a sound like an hi/low/hi/low tone.

This is easily done with the API by Linea Pro using their DTDevice.h playSound method.

Answer (score 2):

I received a solution from Honeywell support.  The solution isn't as nice as the LineaPro API because you can't send it a stream of bytes for sound frequency and duration.

Here's the snippet from Tech Support.

"We don’t have any upcoming SDKs that would add the same type of capability to the Captuvo.  What I think you could do is send beep commands directly to the Captuvo scanner’s beeper using the SDK pass through mode.  The important part is understanding how to use pass through mode.  There should be some documentation in the help file, but I can try to explain here.  When using pass through mode you can send any firmware command supported by the Captuvo scanner.  If you want to make the scanner beep or razz you can send the firmware command [syn]M[cr]bepexe1. for a good read beep and [syn]M[cr]bepexe4. for a RAZZ tone.  You could send a string of these commands to change the sound to something unique for various situations."

Here’s a code snippet.
The menu commands to send via the pass through function would be as follows:
[syn]M[cr]bepexe1.
[syn]M[cr]bepexe4.

[syn] is the hex value 16.  M is the hex value 4D and [cr] is the hex value 0D.

```
const Byte msg[]= {0x16,0x4d,0x0d,'B','E','P','E','X','E','1'.'};
NSData* msgData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&msg length:sizeof(msg)]; [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice]decoderPassThrough:msgData expectingReturnData:YES];
```

Here's a brief snippet of my code implementation for alternative sounds.  I think there's only two sound pitches that I can find from the Honeywell device.

//  1 = good beep
 //  4 = razz beep

```
    const Byte msg1[]= {0x16,0x4d,0x0d,'B','E','P','E','X','E','1','.'};
    NSData* msgData1 = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&msg1 length:sizeof(msg1)];


    const Byte msg4[]= {0x16,0x4d,0x0d,'B','E','P','E','X','E','4','.'};
    NSData* msgData4 = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&msg4 length:sizeof(msg4)];


    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice]decoderPassThrough:msgData1 expectingReturnData:YES];
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice]decoderPassThrough:msgData4 expectingReturnData:YES];


    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice]decoderPassThrough:msgData1 expectingReturnData:YES];
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice]decoderPassThrough:msgData4 expectingReturnData:YES];
```

Comment: Here's a code snippet of the LineaPro since I support both devices internally.  This is my equivelent example of the razz.  Not quite the same frequence pitch but it works.

int soundbytes[]={3000,300,2000,300,3000,300,2000,300};
        
[self.dtdev playSound:volume beepData:soundbytes length:sizeof(soundbytes) error:nil];

Answer (score 0):

I have converted the great solution by Nick N for use with Swift 3:

```
let goodBeep = NSData(bytes: [0x16,0x4d,0x0d,0x42,0x45,0x50,0x45,0x58,0x45,0x31,0x2e] as [UInt8], length: 11)
let badBeep = NSData(bytes: [0x16,0x4d,0x0d,0x42,0x45,0x50,0x45,0x58,0x45,0x34,0x2e] as [UInt8], length: 11)

if(isInInventory){
    Captuvo.sharedCaptuvoDevice().decoderPassThrough(goodBeep as Data!, expectingReturnData: false)
}
else{
    Captuvo.sharedCaptuvoDevice().decoderPassThrough(badBeep as Data!, expectingReturnData: false)
}
```

Where `goodBeep` is the hex array for the high pitched tone and `badBeep` for the razz tone, and `isInInventory` is a Bool you can set true or false depending on your situation